# How to reuse two or more variables in a custom column in DataTables?

Tags: datatables

I found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41908989/1661640) in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41900533/datatables-rendering-custom-column).

In the answer, it says:

```
"mData": "Name",
"mRender": function (data, type, row) {
  return "<a href='Admin/Categories/Edit/" + data + "'>EDIT</a>";
```

I'm look for a way to include two variables, for instance:

```
"mData": ["Name", "User"],
"mRender": function (data, type, row) {
  return "<a href='Admin/Categories/Edit/" + data[0] + data[1] + "'>EDIT</a>";
```

Is there any way I can do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `row` argument contains all the data for that row. The `data` argument contains the data specified in the column options. So you would do something like

```js
data: 'Name',
render: (data, type, row) => `<a href="Admin/Categories/Edit/${data}/${row.User}">EDIT</a>`
```

or you could set the `data` property as `null` and just use the `row` argument

```js
data: null,
render: (data, type, row) => `<a href="Admin/Categories/Edit/${row.Name}/${row.User}">EDIT</a>`
```